# /proc/net/netstat not found

Tags: kernel, proc, openwrt, netstat, net

I am trying to compile my own Linux for embededd devices, using the OpenWRT distribution. I am trying to get some Multicast information using the `/proc/net/netstat` interface but it is not found (normally this is available on my desktop).

If I am right this should be enabled in the `kernel_menuconfig` but I am not able to find any option related to this.

**UPDATE**: i was trying with kernel `3.10.49`and `4.4.14`. In both cases `proc.c` is compiled (`proc.o` is available in my `build_dir`, `/proc` is mounted, but `/proc/net/netstat` does not exists.

Comment: Which what kernel version(s) are you working?

Comment: I am using kernel version 3.10.49

Comment: Do you see anything in `/proc`?  Is it mounted?  In 4.9.6 `/proc/net/netstat` is implemented in `net/ipv4/proc.c`.  Would there be some reason that's not getting compiled in your case?

Comment: @AndyDalton the `/proc` is mounted, and many files also exists (i.e. `/proc/net/udp`)

I have checked my `build_dir` and  `net/ipv4/proc.o` is compiled. And you are right, there are entries in the `proc.c`for creating the `/proc/net/netstat`entry, but havent find any macro which can exclude this during compiling the kernel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a while I have just returned to this issue, and finally solved it.
The problem is, that OpenWRT is pathcing the kernel source, and an extra option should be **disabled**, namely the `CONFIG_PROC_STRIPPED`. This is located in

`(make) kernel_menuconfig -> File systems -> Pseudo filesystems -> [ ] Strip non-essential /proc functionality to reduce code size`

The way it was figured out is looking at the patched version of kernel source, not the official one.
Thank you for all the effort you made!

Answer (score 0):

/proc/net/netstat is generated by net/ipv4/proc.c.
net/ipv4/proc.c in the ip_proc_init_net() function, it is generated as proc_create() like the following source.
[image]

You said that net/ipv4/proc.o was compiled.
As shown in the source, net/ipv4/proc.c creates /proc/net/sockstat,netstat and snmp.
The /proc/net/udp have created is generated by net/ipv4/udp.c.

First look for sockstat and snmp in /proc/net/ .
Also, make sure that the ip_proc_init_net () function in net/ipv4/proc.c has generated an error with the proc_create() function.
If an error occurs in that part, you must find the cause of the error.

Comment: @KwonTaeYoung Thank you for your answer.
I have deleted `proc.o` and recompiled my kernel with high debuglevel. There was no error, it just compiled fine  


`CC      net/ipv4/proc.o`  


I was going through my `/proc/net` directory again, and found that `/proc/net/sockstat6` exists, but`/proc/net/sockstat` is also missing (same with `snmp6 and `snmp`).

Comment: @GABIKA6 Check whether the proc_create () of net/proc/ipv4.c is executed normally. ex) printk(). Even if the compile is done, it may not work if an error occurred in proc_create().

Comment: no error noticed neither during compile time, nor during booting the device

Comment: @GABIKA6 Did you `check pritnk()` further? `remove_proc_entry(" netstat ", net-> proc_net);` Please check OK. `net/ipv4/proc.c` total 2 is now.